# Stop bash from printing the executed command

Tags: bash

I was trying to learn bash and entered some commands and now each time, I type something like `ls`, the shell prints it out first and then the list of files. How can I revert back to the previous condition where the command executed is not echoed?

**Current behavior**

```
$ ls
ls
sleepy.sh
```

**Previous behavior**

```
$ ls
sleepy.sh
```

Comment: I wonder whether you've enabled "verbose" mode with `set -v`? In that case, disable it again with `set +v`.  Is this an issue in all terminals where you run `bash`?

Comment: @Kusalananda, I tried opening a new terminal after your post. It isn't the case. You also made me realize that I ran `/bin/bash -v` thinking that it would print the version and that is what you are referring to. You can write an answer and I will accept.

Comment: Ah. No. The version of `bash` is had with `bash --version`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's most likely due to enabling "verbose" mode in the shell with `set -v` or `set -o verbose`.  You will also enter this mode if you start the shell with the `-v` option, as in `bash -v` or `bash -o verbose`.  In this mode, the shell will print out each command before executing it.

You may disable this mode by using `set +v` or `set +o verbose`.

If you see this behaviour is a *new* shell, i.e. when you open up a new terminal, then you have `set -v` or `set -o verbose` somewhere in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` files.  Remove that and start again.

---

[From comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/557352/stop-bash-from-printing-the-executed-command/557353#comment1035490_557352), it is clear that this was indeed caused by starting the shell with `bash -v` in the belief that this would output the version of `bash`.

The version of the `bash` shell may be had with `bash --version`, or by outputting the value of `$BASH_VERSION` in the shell.

Comment: where can I find the information for the flags `-v` and `-o`? `man set` doesn't provide information on those flags.

Comment: @heretoinfinity Since `set` is a utility built into the shell itself, it will be documented in the same manual as `bash` (`man bash`).  From an interactive `bash` shell, you can read the documentation of any built-in utility with `help utilityname` (e.g. `help set`).

Comment: thanks. I suppose the only way to keep it from `cat`ing on my screen is to pipe it to less.

Comment: @heretoinfinity Yes. The `help` command does not automatically use a pager (`man` uses the command specified in the `PAGER` environment variable as pager). Piping to `less` may be what you need to do for `help set`.

Comment: Thanks again. I didn't know there was a `PAGER` environment variable.

Comment: @heretoinfinity `man` uses `MANPAGER` or `PAGER`. You can also use `man -P less ...` or `man --pager=less ...` to use `less` explicitly. This is described in the `man` manual (`man man`).

Comment: So I `printenv`ed and I don't have that environment variable. How does the man page know what to use?

Comment: @heretoinfinity As per the `man` manual, "By default, `pager` is used.", so I presume there's a `pager` command, which may well be another name for `less` or `more`.

Comment: It is much more convenient to just download the whole Bash manual in pdf form, you can find everything there. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/

Comment: @SantaXL The issue with that (and with reading manuals on the web in general) is that the manual _on your system_ documents the tool _on your system_, while a manual on the web may document some other version of the tool.  The thing you linked to, for example, documents version 5 of `bash`. A macOS user (for example) would be running version 3.2.57 if they are using their default `bash`.  Other tools have totally different options depending on what Unix you are running.  The `man` command always documents the tool that is actually installed.

Comment: This is how I ended up in this original question. I am on a mac and wanted to know what version I had given that the tutorial I was following was running things on Linux. Checking the version erroneously led to the question and the string of comments - which I am frankly very thankful for since I learned a lot from Kusalananda.

Comment: @heretoinfinity On macOS, you may want to look into installing a fresher verison of `bash` using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

Comment: Got the new version installed. 5.0.11